# officejs dialog (Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync) not appearing in browser

Tags: office365, office-js, office-addins, officedev

I use the following code to reveal the dialog. In MacOS Word 365 desktop, the dialog is revealed and works as documented:

```js
let dialog; 

function openDialog(url, successUrl) {
  Office.onReady((info) => {
    if (info.host === Office.HostType.Word) {
      console.log(info);
      Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(
        url,
        { height: 50, width: 30, displayInIframe: false }, // size of the dialog box
        (res) => {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
          if (res.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
            console.log("Display dialog separate window");
            dialog = res.value; // set the dialog variable declared earlier
            dialog.addEventHandler(
              Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived,
              (arg) => {
                dialog.close();
                const { message } = arg; // we want the string "true"
                if (message === "true") {
                  window.location.replace(successUrl);
                }
              }
            );
          }
        }
      );
    }
  });
}
```

When using the same code with the same manifest.xml (sideloaded into office for the web for both Chrome and Edge), instead of the prompt (that checks for popup-blockers) appearing in the main window.... it appears in the taskpane:

[It seems like the dialog from Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync is only appearing within the taskpane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KB1h7.png)

And on clicking on allow, a brief dialog box appears but vanishes immediately. The following logs appear in the console (per the code above:

```
{"value":{},"status":"succeeded"} 
Display dialog separate window
```

As mentioned, the same code above already works in MacOS 365 but fails in office for the web.

*EDIT 1:* The dialog properly shows up as a separate window within the Mac Word client and the functions related to the dialog opening and closing work per the documentation.

*EDIT 2:* Narrowed down the issue to the `<script>link-to-office-js</script>` within the dialog url causing the vanishing the dialog. See minimal [scriptlab implementation](https://github.com/OfficeDev/script-lab/issues/1017) and [issue raised in Github](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/3673)

Comment: Please give more details about the difference between what you expect to see and what you actually see. You say it works in Mac, but what does that mean? What do you see in Mac and what do you see in Office on the web? Screenshots would help. Also, can you duplicate this behavior in Script Lab?

Comment: Thank you for the reply @RickKirkham.

I've uploaded the screenshots in a Github issue https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/3586

When I say it works in Mac, I mean that the dialog properly shows up as a separate window within the Mac Word client and the functions related to the dialog opening and closing work per the documentation.

I've tried creating a minimal repo to reproduce the issue but even sideloading a yeoman generated template on the web (to demo the dialog) isn't working per an issue I added just now: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs-pr/issues/4139

Comment: As to duplicating the behavior in Script Lab, I understand that the dialog url needs to be the same as host domain. Since Script Lab uses its own separate domain in its taskpane, I am unable to use the dialog method without getting the following `AsyncResult`: 

`{"status":"failed","error":{"name":"Display Dialog Error","message":"The domain of the URL is not included in the AppDomains element in the manifest, and is not subdomain of source location.","code":12004}}`

Comment: Managed to solve this myself via another stack overflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77111116/how-to-load-officejs-in-dialog-from-taskpane-office-for-web).