# How to load officejs in dialog from taskpane office for web?

Tags: office365, ms-office, office-js, office-addins, office-dialog-api

The recommended way to [reference officejs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/referencing-the-javascript-api-for-office-library-from-its-cdn) is via CDN script at the `<head>`.

If we do this in the taskpane html and call [Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins), the target url is opened in a nonmodal non-iframe "dialog".

If I place the same reference officejs in this target url, it fails, resulting in the dialog closing immediately, i.e.

```html
<!--- Placing this script causes errors in the target dialog url, causing the dialog to close immediately -->
<head>
    <script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js"></script>
</head>
```

I've since added an [issue on officejs](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/3673) and created a [minimal reproduction of the problem via scriptlab](https://github.com/OfficeDev/script-lab/issues/1017).

But in the event someone more knowledgeable can answer it here, it'd be much appreciated.

I've tried excluding office reference from the dialog url and just navigating to a subsequent url that contains the office reference but this fails as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case this is able to help someone later. I do not think it is documented or maybe it's implied by the use of officejs in an iframe context.

Apparently, my localhost was serving the dialog url with the response header `Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin-allow-popups`, once i switched this off, the dialog url was able to properly load the OfficeJS reference in the head.

Answer (score 1):

You should not do this, or need to. There are only four Office.js APIs that you can call in the dialog opened with a call to `displayDialogAsync`:

- initialize
- onReady
- isSetSupported
- messageParent

Office loads these in the dialog automatically, so you don't need to. If you haven't done so already, I recommend that you read [Use the Office dialog API in Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins).

Comment: Thank you taking the time to reply. Yes I've gone through the documentation. The issue I was having was that the dialog would immediately close in office online because the officejs script was erroring out. I managed to narrow down the issue via a response header in the dialog url.

Answer (score 0):

this is full code check it hopefully this is helpful for you @justmars.

```js
Office.onReady(function (info) {
var adddialog;

function AddofficeDialog () {
     Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync('https://localhost:44326/yourdialog.html', { height: 60, width: 35 }, //replace your localhost and your dialog.html
         function (asyncResult) {
             adddialog = asyncResult.value;
             adddialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, addprocessMessage);
         }
     );
 };

 function addprocessMessage(arg) {
     adddialog.close();
     var message = arg.message;
     console.log(message);
 };  
});
```

and add this in your Dialog.htmi file

```
Office.onReady(function (info) {
function CloseDialog(){
 var data = {
 Lead: "AddLead",,
 Description: "AddDescription",
 Link: "AddLink",
  };

 var jsondata = JSON.stringify(data)
 Office.context.ui.messageParent(jsondata);
} 
});
```

call this function when you want to close dialog and (jsondata) you can send data to your main page from dialog.
and also add this office link in your dialog.html page

```
 <script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting, M Junaid. I believe I've resolved the issue by means of removing the response header `Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin-allow-popups` from the url (which in your example is `https://localhost:44326/yourdialog.html`). The presence of the header prevented the office script from loading.

Comment: okay, its good if you resolve the issue I am just showing you a good example how it works correctly.

Comment: hi @justmars if my Answer is Good and correct then you can accept it. may be it is helpful for others.

Comment: Unfortunately, the example provided, however helpful, doesn't answer the question. I've already answered my own question in the attempt to help others. Should I come across another answer of yours in the future, I'll be sure to upvote it.